# Android Bottom Sheet Dialog

Tags: android, layout

```
package com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh.LoginActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh.R;

public class Events extends AppCompatActivity{

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.event);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheerDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Events.this);
            View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
            bottomSheerDialog.setContentView(parentView);
            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(View)parentView.getParent();
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,200,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            bottomSheerDialog.show();
        }
    });


}

}
```

Error Code :
Error:(30, 89) error: ';' expected
Error:(31, 54) error: '.class' expected
Error:(31, 55) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

line 30 : BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(View)parentView.getParent();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to pass the `parentView` in the `BottomSheetBehaviour.from()` like this

```
public class Events extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.event);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheerDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Events.this);
                View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
                bottomSheerDialog.setContentView(parentView);
                BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parentView.getParent());
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(int); TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,200,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                bottomSheerDialog.show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: yes , but now new error  is
Error:(36, 58) error: '.class' expected
Error:(36, 59) error: ';' expected  
line 36 : bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight
                            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,200,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());